# Une question sur les verbes pronominaux

Tags: grammaire, verbes, verbes-pronominaux

Quand j'utilise les verbes pronominaux, puis-je dire:

> nous aimons téléphonez-eux

au lieu de

> nous s'aimons téléphoner

ou les deux sont incorrects?

S'il vous plait excusez-moi pour les erreurs grammaticales :)

Answer (score 5):

Les deux sont incorrects.

- Nous aimons leur téléphoner.
- Nous aimons nous téléphoner.

Comment: ah je vous remercie ! mais j'ai également une autre question: quel est la différence entre "eux" et "leur" ?

Comment: Quelle est ta langue maternelle?

Comment: Ma langue maternelle est anglais et j'apprends le français depuis 3 ans.

Comment: eux = *them*, leur = *their* ou *to them*.